# How do I replicate the unique crispiness of Korean fried chicken?

Tags: chicken, korean-cuisine

I recently tasted Korean fried chicken and I was surprised at the crispiness and texture. It's unlike anything that I have had before. I looked up some recipes online and it seems that there's more cornstarch in the recipe than flour. Some recipes, like [this one](http://www.maangchi.com/recipe/yangnyeom-tongdak), uses potato starch and sweet rice flour with some regular flour.

What is it about these other dry ingredients that give the chicken this other kind of light crunchiness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not so much the dry ingredients as it is the cooking technique, which involves double frying the chicken.

You'll notice that the recipe you link instructs you to double fry the chicken, and so do others like this one: http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2010/04/dinner-tonight-korean-fried-chicken-recipe.html

Comment: I'm familiar with double frying to get added crispiness...but there's still something different/special about the batter/dry ingredients, perhaps.

Comment: Well I haven't experimented with different batters, but the K(orean)FC I make seems to have a thinner batter overall. The key may be both the batter and the double frying. But I really love the double frying technique. Chicken not double fried definitely doesn't have the same texture.